# jQuery - set div height equal to div width

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a responsive website that has a grid of squares. So I need the height of each div (with a class of 'main') to be the same as the div width when it resizes. I'm quite new to jQuery so I was hoping somebody could tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

```
var divWidth = $('.main').width(); 

$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.main').height() = divWidth;
});
```

Many thanks!

Comment: try it without the `var` before `divWidth`.. var scopes it..

Comment: You might want to calculate the width on page resize as well.  $('.main').height($(this).width());

Comment: Did people seriously just copy and paste eachother's answers??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
var divWidth = $('.main').width(); 

$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.main').height(divWidth);
});
```

Comment: What's the difference between your code and the other two answers?

Comment: Thanks very much. I chose this as the answer as it was the first one. The answers are the same because my question was so simple. I'm such a noob! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 8):

You should not declare the `divWidth` outside the scope of the resize() function, because the value will not be updated when the resize event is fired. Also, there is a risk that there may be multiple `.main` elements. Either use an ID, or loop through all classes (if there are multiple instances).

Try this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    // If there are multiple elements with the same class, "main"
    $('.main').each(function() {
        $(this).height($(this).width());
    });

    // Or you can switch to using an ID
    $('#main').height($('#main').width());
}).resize();
```

You fire the resize() event again to ensure that the size is set upon loading.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var divWidth = $('.main').width(); 

$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.main').height(divWidth);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var divWidth = $('.main').width(); 

$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.main').height( divWidth );
});
```

Note that the `height()` will give you the height when calling with no arguments, but with an argument, it will change the height of the object ;)